Wifi disconnects on two different laptops after upgrading to 24.10
Wifi disconnects on two different laptops after upgrade to 24.10.
Upgraded from 24.04 to 24.10 and now the Wifi drops.

Requests authentication password. Enter password and no connection.
Turn Off Wifi.
Turn On Wifi, click the Arrow to view networks.
Click to select my Home Network and then Wifi connects.
A few minutes later, Wifi Requests Authentication Password again.
This repeats endlessly.

In the terminal I ran:  lshw -C network :
WARNING: you should run this program as super-user.
  *-network
description: Ethernet interface
product: RTL810xE PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller
vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
physical id: 0
bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
logical name: enp1s0
version: 07
serial: 7c:8a:e1:09:58:d3
size: 100Mbit/s
capacity: 100Mbit/s
width: 64 bits
clock: 33MHz
capabilities: bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=6.13.0-061300rc1-generic duplex=full firmware=rtl8106e-1_0.0.1 06/29/12 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=100Mbit/s
       resources: irq:31 ioport:3000(size=256) memory:f0500000-f0500fff memory:f0200000-f0203fff
  *-network
       description: Wireless interface
       product: QCA9377 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter
       vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: wlp2s0
       version: 31
       serial: 10:63:c8:df:ae:21
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=ath10k_pci driverversion=6.13.0-061300rc1-generic firmware=WLAN.TF.2.1-00021-QCARMSWP-1 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:37 memory:f0000000-f01fffff
WARNING: output may be incomplete or inaccurate, you should run this program as super-user.

In the terminal I ran: sudo rm -r /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/*
rm: cannot remove '/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/*':  
No such file or directory 

In the terminal I ran:  sudo systemctl restart NetworkManager
And both the hard wired and the Wifi turn on.
I have to select the Wifi Network to connect. Sometimes it connects, and sometimes it opens the Authentication Password Required and does not connect.

Is wifi power management enabled?  Atheros devices don't work well in linux when it is on
